# error: The getter 'ltr' isn't defined for the class 'TextDirection'

Tags: dart, flutter

any one can tell  me about this error 
thx .

```
Text("مرحبا بالعالم",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 17),
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                              ),
```

> error: The getter 'ltr' isn't defined for the class 'TextDirection'

[Error](https://i.ibb.co/WDj9hqN/Untitled-2-copy.jpg)

Comment: Post your code with error

Answer (score 70):

I know its way too late but for anyone having the same problem do this

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

then use

```
textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr
```

in your text widget

Comment: should be accepted . the only worked solution for me

Comment: I had a conflict with ``NumberFormat()`` class where you import ``'package:intl/intl.dart'`` and the ``TextDirection.ltr``  isn't defined anymore. Because the package intl also got class named ``TextDirection`` which is needs to change. Thanks for your answer, another way for ``TextDirection``!

Comment: however, i chose to do  "  import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl ;  " instead, since i had already done alot of forms. found it easier to apply this.

Comment: This is the answer and should be accepted.

Comment: Thank you so much , iwas losing my damn mind

Answer (score 33):

Error with these lib.
`import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`

so you can use it like
`import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and it confused me because i wasn't using the `intl` package.. but since i used the `easy_localization` package and this one itself uses the `intl` package.. i figured it out that i have to hide the `TextDirection` class from it:

```dart
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart' hide TextDirection;
```

i hope this could help anyone out there :D

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I had!

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find a complete solution for noobs above. Just replacing libraries gave other errors. Complete solution below.

Change:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'
```

To:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;
```

Then add intl before all depending packages, such as Datetime:

```
intl.DateFormat()
```

Done.

Answer (score 4):

I faced like this problem, that happened because you use "intl" for date formatting I guess, so you must use a parameter when you import intl like this:
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'as intl;
and in your code use 
intl.DateFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy', 'en_US',) 
and you see after that the error was disappeared.

Comment: this answer EXACTLY as upvoted answer above, nothing new

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score -1):

I tried this

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        "مرحبا بالعالم",
        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
        textDirection: TextDirection.LTR,//make it uppercase LTR or RTL
      ),
    );
  }
```

Works fine.

Comment: did ctrl + click take you to source code in text.dart file?

Comment: class TextDirection {
  static const LTR = const TextDirection._('LTR', 'ltr');
  static const RTL = const TextDirection._('RTL', 'rtl');

Comment: Your code works fine. Like i pasted. no error. Can you go to the source code of error by Control+click on `ltr`?

Comment: yes take me and i can see rtl but not work i'm tried to restart my pc and android studio but stale no working

Comment: no i cant go on Control+click on ltr  but i can go when RTL but stale error

Comment: @MoradNAbdulkhaliq I think I found it.

Comment: @MoradNAbdulkhaliq the code you got on ctrl-click shows some internal code changes.

Comment: not yet i can't solve my problem I tried clean flutter But the problem still exists